# Vertically centred div which increases parent height

Tags: html, css, transform, center

There is a div which has a dynamic content. The height of the parent is 100% of the body and child is unknown. translateY(-50%) technique works good only if a child content height is less than parent. But if it's more child div(green) starts to overflow the parent (yellow) as on below image.
[image]
What's a proper way to set parent div increase the height and add some paddings.

```css
.body {
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
.parent {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(105, 199, 115);
   
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show some source?

Comment: I've updated the question. Also updated that my parent div has a 100% window size, not a 100vh.

Comment: You need `min-height` on the parent instead of `height`. That won't work with the absolutely positioned child though. Hm. Must think.

Comment: By default the parent will increase in size of the child, but in your case it has `position:absolute` so that won't work [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbZMyE?editors=110) is an example how it works with just margin centering. Do you have to use absolute positioning in your project? and the parent div will alaways be limited to 300px of the body height in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why positions?!
You can center div With this:
I use this for center a div with dynamic height in it's parent:

```
<style>
    .body {
        height: 300px;
        background: red;
        display:table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .parent {
        display:table-cell; 
        vertical-align: middle;
        background: rgb(105, 199, 115);

    }
    .child {

        background: green;
        width: 200px;
        margin: auto;
    }
</style>
<div class="body">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, Sample content, 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```