# Vertical align middle button in div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically align this button in the center of the modal-footer `div`.  Here is a link to my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kris_redden/34jyLpok/

```css
.modal-footer {
  background-color: #2A3E5D;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.wrapper-div {
  vertical-align: middle
}

.button {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
  <div class="wrapper-div">
    <button type="button" class="button"> Submit Filters </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what needs to change in order for this to be vertically aligned in the center of the blue modal-footer div.  I know can accomplish this in a hacky way by putting margins on the button but that isn't what I want to do.

Comment: You can see this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33852909/vertically-centred-div-which-increases-parent-height/33853079#33853079)

Comment: A negative is obviously an award.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.modal-footer {
display: table;
width: 100%;
}

.wrapper-div {
display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

Go for something like this. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34jyLpok/5/).

Answer (score 67):

Easiest would be to add the following to .modal-footer

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Comment: What about the support for maximum browsers.

Comment: use autoprefixer

Comment: I think the better solution would be to use less code.

Answer (score 14):

this can also be achieved by using

```
.button-container{
 position:relative;
 height:100%;
}

.button{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

`vertical-align:middle;` is not necessary here. i would use this method if button container height is unknown and if i could not use flex-box (`dispaly:flex;`) instead.
https://jsfiddle.net/34jyLpok/7/

another option is to use flex-box (`display:flex;`)

```
.button-container{
     height:100%;
     display: flex;
     //flex-direction: column;//only vertical
     align-items: center;//both vertical and horizonal
     justify-content: center
    }

    .button{
      width:100px;
    }
```

the problem with `display: flex` is that it is not fully supported in old IE browser versions. 
https://jsfiddle.net/34jyLpok/9/

Answer (score 3):

You can use flexbox as shown below

```
.modal-footer {
  background-color: #2A3E5D;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your style to this

```
.modal-footer {
  background-color: #2A3E5D;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper-div {
  display:table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.button {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  display: block;
  margin:auto;
  font-size: 12px
  position: relative;
}
```

You can remove `margin:auto;` from `.button` to only vertically center button

See on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34jyLpok/4/)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it.

```css
.wrapper-div {
  line-height: 60px; // ex: 60px, The button will center to line-height.
}

.wrapper-div button {
  // height of button must be less than its parent.
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-div">
  <button type="button" class="button"> Submit Filters </button>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-div">
  <button type="button" class="button"> Submit Filters </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want to give heights in px